# Google calendar not working

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

Google calendar not working properly, Getting an error "**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid code' in E:\Extrawork\wamp\www\alpha\application\modules\myaccount\controllers\google-api\src\Google\Client.php**"
Can someone help me please and thank you ?

```
    public function google_api(){
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        require_once('google-api/vendor/autoload.php');


        define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
        define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/credential/credential.json');
        define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '\google-api\client_secret.json');

        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json
        define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
          Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY)
        ));

        // Get the API client and construct the service object.
        $client = $this->getClient();
        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

        // Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
        $calendarId = 'primary';
        $optParams = array(
          'maxResults' => 10,
          'orderBy' => 'startTime',
          'singleEvents' => TRUE,
          'timeMin' => date('c'),
        );
        $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

        if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
          print "No upcoming events found.\n";
        } else {
          print "Upcoming events:\n";
          foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
            $start = $event->start->dateTime;
            if (empty($start)) {
              $start = $event->start->date;
            }
            printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
          }
        }
        if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
          throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
        }

    }

    // Code Start
    /**
     * Returns an authorized API client.
     * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
     */
    function getClient() {
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
      $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
      $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);

      $client->setAccessType('offline');

      // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
      $credentialsPath = $this->expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
      if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
      } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

        // Store the credentials to disk.
        if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
          mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
        printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
      }
      $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

      // Refresh the token if it's expired.
      if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
      }
      return $client;
    }

    /**
     * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
     * @param string $path the path to expand.
     * @return string the expanded path.
     */
    function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
      $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
      if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
        $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
      }
      return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
    }
    // Code End
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was credential.json file in credential folder was not generated before. I was getting a string in my web browser as below
**https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=XXXXXXX&redirect_uri=XXXXX&state&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&approval_prompt=auto**
I got a code when I open this url in my web browser. I have copied that code and replaced  $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN)) with  $authCode = trim(CODE_I_GOT).
This process has generated credential.json file and after that I was able to run my code successfully

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem, is it possible to see a screen shot of it working or the code itself  because as I do as you said I'm getting an entirely different error and I'm unable to run my code

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/785) which stated that maybe the reason why API is throwing a 'Invalid code' exception is that the format for access token does not match with the format generated in new API.

This code might also help:

> - while getting contents, I used serialize function
>
>   - Example: `$accessToken = serialize (file_get_contents($credentialsPath));`
> - while inserting contents, I used deserialize function
>
>   - Example: `$accessToken = derialize(file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken););`

Try inserting `serialize()` in all places that write `$accessToken` and `unserialize()` in all places that read `$accessToken` can fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response, But I did try this already, I find no success. I am not sure but I believe there is something wrong with "CREDENTIALS_PATH".